# Как вызвать taskkill только для запущенного процесса?

Tags: php, windows, cmd, php7, php7.4

Мне необходимо вызвать taskkill Excel если он запущен. Если он не запущен то, он выводит консоль некрасивую ошибку. Мне бы ее не хотелось видеть.

```
popen('taskkill /IM "EXCEL.EXE" /F', 'r');
```

```
ERROR: The process "EXCEL.EXE" not found.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разобралась.

```
$handle = popen('TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq EXCEL.exe"', 'r');
$result = fread($handle, 1024);
if (!contains($result,'INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.'))
    popen('taskkill /IM "EXCEL.EXE" /F', 'r');
```

Возможно строку с ошибкой нужно будет отлавливать в русском варианте или в другом в зависимости от локализации ОСи.

contains - самописная функция, взятая из проекта.

**UPD**

Решение от **Daemon-5**.

```
popen('taskkill /IM "EXCEL.EXE" /F >NUL 2>NUL', 'r');
```

Comment: чтобы отслеживать ошибку, читайте значение переменной **%ERRORLEVEL%**, после вызова taskkill. Когда процесс успешно "убит" - значение **0**. Если не найден, - обычно - **128**. Как вариант, добавить вывод любой строки поле вызова команды. Но есть вариант проще скрыть вывод: **@taskkill /f /im excel.exe  >NUL  2>NUL**

Comment: @Daemon-5, спасибо! Помогло!